# how to load the component on loading the page using vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have this code that works only if you click on the " / " but i want those components to load when i land on the page not have to click on it

```
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }
const Baz = { template: '<div>baz</div>' }

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/',
      components: {
        default: Foo,
        a: Bar,
        b: Baz
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/other',
      components: {
        default: Baz,
        a: Bar,
        b: Foo
      }
    }
  ]
})
    
  

      new Vue({
            router,
          el: '#app'
        })
```

my router file

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Named Views</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/">/</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/other">/other</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <router-view class="view one"></router-view>
  <router-view class="view two" name="a"></router-view>
  <router-view class="view three" name="b"></router-view>
</div>
```

I want Foo and Bar and Baz to be loaded without needing to click on it

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/posva/6du90epg/)

Answer (score 1):

Push the `/other` route in the router inside the mounted hook :

```
new Vue({
    router,
  el: '#app',
  
  mounted(){
  this.$router.push('/other')
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , it works in this instance but what if I have a vue page and i want to do the same thing there. i tried the mounted and it doens't work

Comment: please explain more the issue*